# Why is urllib2.urlopen(url) in python not faster but slower when I use multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib2

I wanted to use multithreading in python to reduce the time of loading different subpages of a webpage with urllib2.urlopen(url). The page I want to load normally takes 4,5 seconds. So my plan was to use multithread to load different subpages of the same page parallel and reduce the overall loading time.

I wrote this example and surprisingly it takes longer with multithreading than the "normal" version one after another.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import time

urls = [
  'http://www.spiegel.de', 'http://www.spiegel.de',  'http://www.spiegel.de', 'http://www.spiegel.de', 'http://www.spiegel.de', 'http://www.spiegel.de', 'http://www.spiegel.de', 'http://www.spiegel.de', 'http://www.spiegel.de', 'http://www.spiegel.de', 'http://www.spiegel.de', 'http://www.spiegel.de', 'http://www.spiegel.de', 'http://www.spiegel.de'
  ]
start = time.time()

for url in urls:
    results = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print(results)
end = time.time()
print("elapsed time no threading: ", end - start)

start = time.time()

# Make the Pool of workers
pool = ThreadPool(4)

# Open the urls in their own threads
# and return the results
results = pool.map(urllib2.urlopen, urls)
print(results)

#close the pool and wait for the work to finish
pool.close()
pool.join()

end = time.time()
print("elapsed time threading: ", end - start)
```

The Result:

```
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x02AF4BF0>
...
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x02AF4C10>
elapsed time no threading:  0.9750549793243408
[<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x02B11330>, ... <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x02B3F8D0>]
elapsed time threading:  3.4091949462890625
```

Comment: I got  `elapsed time no threading:  11.698709964752197` and `elapsed time threading:  3.2182838916778564`

Comment: As I say it depends on the variation in loading time. Sometimes the threaded version is faster sometimes the non threading. I think the thought of making a crawler faster through parallalization isn't logical because parallelization does not improve my or the server's loading speed.

Comment: Is your question "how is this possible"? or "how can I speed things up"?

Comment: Rather "how can I speed things up"...

Comment: Are you aware of [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)?